# Shared element transition animation to/from a full screen activity

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I've created a shared element transition animation between an ImageView located on a RecyclerView in Activity A to a full screen ImageView in Activity B.
I've noticed that if Activity B is marked in its theme with:

> ```
>     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
> ```

then when coming back from Activity B to Activity A the transition ends with an annoying "jump" when the status bar is being displayed again.

Any idea how to solve this?

p.s.
Im not using any overridePendingTransition between the activities and the shared element transition is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

**Activity A**: not fullscreen;
**Activity B**: fullscreen;

Just add this:

**In A**:

```
setExitSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
                 getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        });
```

**In B**:

```
@Override
public void finishAfterTransition() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.finishAfterTransition();
}
```

Hope this helps~

Comment: Even though this is not the marked answer, this solution did work for me. Thanks!